# output layer regularization implementation

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, constraints, regularized

I’m building a NN model using keras, and I wish to impose a constraint on it that doesn’t (directly) have to do with the weights. Would be very grateful for some help / points me towards some relevant keywords to look up. The constraint I wish to impose is a bit complex, but it can be simplified in the following manner: I wish to impose a constraint on the output of certain inputs of the net. For the sake of simplicity, let’s say the constraint looks like NN(3)+NN(4) < 10, where NN is the neural net, which can be seen as a function. How can I impose such a constraint? Thank you very much in advance for any help on the subject!

edit: A more detailed explanation of what I'm trying to do and why.
The theoretical model I'm building is this:
[image: Theoretical Model]
I'm feeding the output of the first net into the input of the second net, along with an additive gaussian noise.
The constraint I wish to impose is on the output of the first NN (g). Why? Without a constraint, the net maps the inputs to outputs as high as it possibly can in order to make the additive noise as insignificant as possible. And rightly so, this *is* the optimal encoding function g, but it's not very interesting :) And so I wish to impose a constraint on the output of the first NN (g). More specifically, the constraint is on the total power of the function: integral{ fX(x) * g(x)^2 dx }. But this can be simplified more or less, to a function that looks something like what I described earlier - g(3)+g(4)<10. More specifically, the function is sum { fX(x) * g(i)^2 * dx } < max_power, for some sampled inputs i.
This is the problem, now here's how I attempted to implement it:

```
model = Sequential([
        Dense(300, input_dim=1, activation='relu'),
        Dense(300, activation='relu'),
        Dense(1, activation='linear', name=encoder_output),
        GaussianNoise(nvar, name='noise'),
        Dense(300, activation='relu', name=decoder_input),
        Dense(300, activation='relu'),
        Dense(1, activation='linear', name=decoder_output),
    ])
```

Mainly, this is supposedly a single neural net, and not really 2 (although there is no difference obviously).
The import things to note is the input dim 1, output dim 1 (x and y in the diagram), and the gaussian noise in the middle. The hidden layers are not very interesting right now, I'll optimize them at a later point.
In this model, I wish to impose a constraint on the output of a (supposedly) hidden layer named encoder_output. Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a multi input/multi output model with shared weights layers. The model could for example look like this:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Add
from keras.models import Model

# Shared weights layers
hidden = Dense(10, activation='relu')
nn_output = Dense(1, activation='relu')

x1 = Input(shape=(1,))
h1 = hidden(x1)
y1 = nn_output(h1)

x2 = Input(shape=(1,))
h2 = hidden(x2)
y2 = nn_output(h2)

# Your constraint
# In case it should be more complicated, you can implement
# a custom keras layer
sum = Add()([y1, y2]) 

model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=[y1, y2, sum])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

X_train_1 = [3,4]
X_train_2 = [4,3]
y_train_1 = [123,456] # your expected output
y_train_2 = [456,123] # your expected output
s = [10,10] # expected sums

model.fit([X_train_1, X_train_2], [y_train_1, y_train_2, s], epochs=10)
```

If you have no exact value for your constraint that can be used as an expected output, you can remove it from the outputs and write a simple custom regularizer that would be used on it. There is a simple example for a custom regularizer in the Keras documentation.

Comment: Hi eric, thanks for your help!
I've edited my original post to include a more detailed explanation of what I'm trying to do. Your answer is an interesting approach, and I'll not sure yet if I can incorporate it to my need, but it's not as direct of a solution as I'd imagined. Let me know if you think it can be used to my problem after reading my detailed explanation.
Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, your constraint is dependant on both the input and the output of g()? If this is the case, maybe use a concatenate layer in a sequential model like this: `reg_layer = Concatenate([input_layer, g_output], activity_regularizer=my_regularizer)`. Then implement a regularizer similar to https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/regularizers.py, where x[0] would be the network input and x[1] the output of g. You can then implement your constraint in the regularizer and not use this concat layer any further in the network.

Comment: To work on dg and dx, you could probably also use an `Add()([x, K.constant(epsilon)])` layer and execute `g()` on it after defining epsilon as you wish.